# Enlazar evento de click a todos los botones creados por un bucle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estoy desarrollando un sistema ERP dirigido a un Bar/Restaurante en WPF como proyecto de final de grado superior de desarrollo de aplicaciones multiplataforma. En la página en la que se realizan las ventas necesito manejar los eventos de un numero de botones variable.

Como podria conseguir el manejo del evento de click en los botones creados en el boocle?

This is the C# Part:

```
 partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public string Content { get; set; }

        public string OnClick { get; set; }
        public int distIzquierda { get; set; }

        public int distArriba { get; set; }
        public IList<Button> Botones { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            crearBotones();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void crearBotones()
        {
`Creation of buttons`
            Botones = new List<Button>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Botones.Add(new Button
                {
                    Name = "btn",
                    Content = i,
                    Width = 200,
                    Height = 100,
                    Margin = new Thickness(10),
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is The XAML part

```
<ScrollViewer
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Botones}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="6"
                                      Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button 
                            Click="{Binding click}"
                            Width="200"
                            Height="110"
                            Content = "{Binding Text}"
                           >
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Estás en [es.so], la pregunta y el título de la misma debe estar en castellano. Por favor traduce lo que falta.

Comment: WPF tiene su propio patron llamado MVVM(Modelo-Vista-Vista-Modelo), es cierto que en WPF puedes programar como si estuvieras programando en el Windows Form clasico, pero recomiendo personalmente que sigas al pie de la letra utilizar la filosofia propia de WPF donde los eventos tienen un tratamiento muy diferente a lo que se esta acostumbrado normalmente y aprender esa filosofia lleva tiempo y estudio para entenderla bien